# IIS6 Server with Modernizr browser detection act different in 2 sites

Tags: jquery, iis-6, modernizr, browser-detection

Hi I have a code that detect user's browser (using Modernizr) and show different file selectors.

Weird thing, I have 2 sites running on the same IIS6 Server, the 2 sites are having exactly the same code, but the browser detection area gives different file selector.

The code is(using Jquery):

```
$("#singleFileUploader").hide();
$("#multipleFileUploader").hide();

//Detect browser
if (isInputAttributeSupported("multiple") == true) {
    $("#multipleFileUploader").show();
}
else {
    $("#singleFileUploader").show();
}
```

On my live site, I see the singleFileUploader, but on my dev site, I see the multipleFileUploader, and multipleFileUploader is what I suppose to see. I doubt that the problem is with the code, I think it might be with the IIS Server but I really can't see what I set differently between 2 sites. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without actually seeing the sites (which would be required to actually help in this case), I would venture a guess that you are using Internet explorer, and you are getting compatibility mode on the live site, and not on the dev site. You can check this by opening up the F12 tools and looking at documentMode.

Comment: Thanks. I believe compatibility mode is the reason. As it is a intranet site, I cannot actually make it to the public. In IE tools -> Compatibility View Tools, there is an option to open all intranet site with compatibility mode, I think that's why it's working when I test locally and not working on when it's on the IIS. But one thing I am too sure, why is IE treating my live site as an intranet site, but dev site is not(when I open it's not in Compatibility mode)? They are set up on the same server but using different port, live is on port 84 and dev is on port 60000.

Comment: Sorry, not sure about that, you'll have to ig through other SO posts to find out